# Jenkins HTML Report published successfully in Log , but not shows in Jenkins build page left menu area

Tags: html, jenkins, build, report

the log shows successful Publish of  HTML report, but not able to see in the Jenkins build page. but I was able to see yesterday, I might have done small modifications in code, will it cause to the disappearance of HTML report? other HTML reports are still available, only a few specific HTML reports are not appearing, but the log is fine.
Any idea?

**LOG :**

[Pipeline] publishHTML
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /opt/jenkins_slave/workspace/xxxxx/target/site/jacoco/testng to /var/jenkins_home/jobs/xxxx-service/branches/develop/builds/615/htmlreports/Coverage_Report_for_Integrated_Testing_(TestNG)
[Pipeline] sh

**Jenkins code :**

```
  steps {     
                unstash "${microServiceName}_sonarqube"  
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'xxxxx', variable: 'xxxxxx')]) {  
                     withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {         
                      sh "mvn -f ${microServiceName}/pom.xml -s $xxxxxx -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true  jacoco:dump -Djacoco.destFile=target/jacoco-testng.exec -Djacoco.address=${jacoco_dump_node_ip} -Djacoco.port=${jacoco_dump_node_port} "                    

                      sh "mvn -f ${microServiceName}/pom.xml -s $xxxxxx -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true jacoco:report@testng-coverage-report -Djacoco.dataFile=target/jacoco-testng.exec"

                      publishHTML([allowMissing: true, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, keepAll: true, reportDir: "${microServiceName}/target/site/jacoco/testng", reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'Coverage Report for Integrated Testing (TestNG)', reportTitles: 'Code Coverage (Jacoco) Report for Integrated Testing (TestNG)'])  

                      sh "mvn -f ${microServiceName}/pom.xml -s $xxxxxx -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true jacoco:merge@merge"

                      sh "mvn -f ${microServiceName}/pom.xml -s $xxxxxx -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true jacoco:report@consolidated-coverage-report -Djacoco.dataFile=target/jacoco-consolidated.exec"

                      publishHTML([allowMissing: true, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, keepAll: true, reportDir: "${microServiceName}/target/site/jacoco/consolidated", reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'Consolidated Coverage Report (TestNG + JUnit)', reportTitles: 'Consolidated Coverage Report (TestNG + JUnit)'])  

                      sh "mvn -f ${microServiceName}/pom.xml -s $xxxxxx -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco-consolidated.exec"                       
                     }
                }  
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant code ?

Comment: @ben5556, i have updated with relevant code

Comment: any help @ben5556 ?

Comment: Did anyone face this issue ?

Comment: DId you solve it?